# php artisan migrate laravel 5.3 give me PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I am new on laravel 5.3 and trying to run php artisan migrate for users table, i am using macbook with MAMP.

The database.php file looks like this:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
```

And the .env look like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I didnt use password for the DB, and i run from the project library "php artisan migrate" and get the:
PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: Re-check your database configuration, and if the server is up and running

Comment: I did all of those and i still getting the same message

Comment: Check if the permissions are well configured for your database

Answer (score 0):

I added to database.php on the mysql section:

```
'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Now its working